# When I copy the contents of one drive, the copy takes up less space. Why?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, filesystems, storage

I am trying to copy the contents of one hard drive to another hard drive.

But once the copy is completed, the copy takes up less space than the original files.

Hence not all files are being copied.

I suspect this might be because after a certain number of folders, the files are not being copied.

Is this correct? And if so, how can I prevent this from happening?

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro

---

SORRY I MEANT 700**GB** NOT **MB**!!

---

I'm trying on Linux now and am going to see if the same happens.

Comment: Also, getting the number of files should not be a problem

Comment: It is possible there are hidden or system files you do not have access to. Do you have attributes set to have access to them all?

Comment: another note: the size on disk is affected by fragmentation.  The ending file size should be smaller if you're going by that record of the two. (Assuming the older location was fragmented.)

Comment: I have edited the OP.

Comment: Don't forget cluster size can also effect size on disk.

Comment: Do the obvious thing. Find out what files are not there and try copying them individually. Basic troubleshooting

Comment: If you have the extra disk space on Drive 1 you could always archive everything and then transfer it. At least that way you know no files will be lost in the transfer of one single (large) archive, and you'd probably get an error if you couldn't access a file when you make the archive.

Comment: Edited again. I meant 700GBs.

Comment: I would Go through the files one by one but that would take ages.

Comment: I didn't think of archiving them! Thanks for the tip!

Will do after I delete all the unwanted files :)

Comment: Remember that under Linux you can use `rsync  -n ` just to print out the files that have to be updated. It exists for windows too. Among the many option available there are a  _"quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or  in  last-modified time_ or a deep check with the option `-c`  _skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size_ of course more slow.

Comment: Possibly, marginally related: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/23408) (even though that is about Unix & Linux).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:
Not necessarily. It can be only the different cluster size between the devices.

**Some words more:**
When you copy a file from a device to another (from an HDD to another) you have to consider even the different cluster sizes. Without entering too deep inside the [zoo of file system type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) it's enough to say here that a partition is organized as an arithmetic exercise book, the bytes are grouped in sector in a similar way in which in the exercise book you can say that the squares are grouped in pages. The index of the free and used space (FAT) is made considering only those *groups*. The sectors can be or free or full, *tertium non datur*.

So a file has a size for the effective bytes used (if it is a text file and contains only the word "*Hi*" it will be 2Bytes), and a size for space used on the device (if a sector is of 4kB it will be a multiple of 4kB, if on another device the sector is of 512 bytes it will be a multiple of 512B).

On the other side it's possible that copying a large number of files you can have errors in writing or reading operations, you can have no right to access to the some file, or some file can be deleted in the meanwhile if the operation is long and the file is a temporary one.

This is usually notified by the program you are using with some error message and with an error exit code.   Under Linux for example, you can catch the exit code by writing in the shell `echo $?`. If it returns a value different from 0 it means error. If you haven't catch those messages in advance, you have to check it *a posteriori*.

After that you copied a large number of files you can check, *quickly*, if the number of the files and the *total effective* bytes count matches. A more effective check can be done computing and comparing the [md5sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) for each file on both the copies. If this match all the contents are Ok. Least you may want to check the permission and date.

Often is cosy to rely on specific tools as [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for Linux, [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) for Windows, or one of the many many other tools available.

Comment: Interesting. A lot of that went over my head in the first read. I honestly never expected file systems and the "allocation unit size" (I assume that's what you were referring to?) to affect how much space a file would take up on a storage device! Thanks a loads!

Comment: You're welcome. I cannot know from here if it is this the cause, but I rely on this steps to find if it is. BTW I didn't have more time to write it simpler.